# Split string to array without <iostream>

Tags: string, type-conversion, std, esp32

I'm building a ESP32 system, that can be configured via QR codes.

The payload I create in an external app  is structured like this

```
[WiFiSSID] + "\n" + [WiFiPassword] + "\n" ...
[User input] + "separator" +...
```

The qr-code recogniser spits out a uint8_t array which I convert into a string.

Now I'd like to split said string into an array of which each member gets stored in EEPROM.

Here comes the tricky part. 
I have a very limited partition size and including  breaks increases the program size too much to fit.

Does anybody have an idea how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

ok I found a way:

I remove chars from separator to separator. Ugly, but works.